# Laravel Eloquent missing local scopes in nested queries

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a reasonably complicated query that utilises the local dynamic scope `permissionableEntity` in the EntityPermission model, simplified below:

```
class EntityPermission
{
    ...

    public function scopeGlobal($query, $global = true)
    {
        return $query->where('isGlobal', $global);
    }

    public function scopePermissionableEntity($query, $entity)
    {
        return $query->where(function($query) use ($entity) {
            $query->global()->orWhere(function($query) use ($entity) {

                $query->whereNotNull('permissionable_uuid')
                      ->withUuid($entity['uuid'], 'permissionable_uuid')
                      ->where('permissionable_type', $entity['type']);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that the use of scope `PermissionableEntity` results in the error in the `scopePermissionableEntity` where closure :

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::global()`

Is anyone able to shed some light on why the $query passed to the subquery is not decorated with the models local scope `scopeGlobal`?

For information

- The project is using Laravel 6.0
- I am using a custom subclass of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` called `Kaie\Foundation\Uuid\Database`. If I look at the class of $query inside the where closure it is the former rather than the latter.
- Error log except to the http stack:

```
local.ERROR: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::global() {"userId":"1d489548-daba-11e9-89f9-080027cbf0c9","exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::global() at /home/vagrant/hydrogen.local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:50)
[stacktrace] 

/home/vagrant/hydrogen.local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(3033): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::throwBadMethodCallException('global')
/home/vagrant/hydrogen.local/modules/Authorisation/Models/UserEntityPermission.php(54): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->__call('global', Array)
[internal function]: Kaie\\Authorisation\\Models\\UserEntityPermission->Kaie\\Authorisation\\Models\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder))
/home/vagrant/hydrogen.local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1339): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder))
/home/vagrant/hydrogen.local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(661): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->whereNested(Object(Closure), 'and')
/home/vagrant/hydrogen.local/modules/Foundation/Uuid/Database/Builder.php(103): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->where(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL, 'and')
/home/vagrant/hydrogen.local/modules/Authorisation/Models/UserEntityPermission.php(72): Kaie\\Foundation\\Uuid\\Database\\Builder->where(Object(Closure))
/home/vagrant/hydrogen.local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(962): Kaie\\Authorisation\\Models\\UserEntityPermission->scopePermissionableEntity(Object(Kaie\\Foundation\\Uuid\\Database\\Builder), Array)
/home/vagrant/hydrogen.local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1313): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->callScope(Array, Array)
/home/vagrant/hydrogen.local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php(23): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->__call('permissionableE...', Array)
/home/vagrant/hydrogen.local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php(385): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\Relation->forwardCallTo(Object(Kaie\\Foundation\\Uuid\\Database\\Builder), 'permissionableE...', Array)
/home/vagrant/hydrogen.local/modules/Authorisation/Traits/HasUserEntityPermissions.php(65): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\Relation->__call('permissionableE...', Array)
/home/vagrant/hydrogen.local/modules/Authorisation/Traits/HasUserEntityPermissions.php(46): Kaie\\Authorisation\\Models\\User->hasDirectPermission(Object(Kaie\\Authorisation\\Models\\Permission), Array)
/home/vagrant/hydrogen.local/modules/Document/Repositories/DocumentRepository.php(122): Kaie\\Authorisation\\Models\\User->hasPermissionTo(Object(Kaie\\Authorisation\\Models\\Permission), Array)
/home/vagrant/hydrogen.local/modules/Foundation/Base/Repositories/GenericRepository.php(25): Kaie\\Document\\Repositories\\DocumentRepository->getBaseListQuery(false, Array)
/home/vagrant/hydrogen.local/modules/Document/Http/Controllers/DocumentController.php(29): Kaie\\Foundation\\Repositories\\GenericRepository->all(Array)
```

Comment: Can you please add the full statement that throws the error?

Comment: @IlGala I have added the log above

Comment: It seems a conflict with that UUID package... It looks like that the `Builder` doesn't inherit the scopes from the model query

Comment: @IlGala what I'm finding confusing is why the query passed to `scopePermissionableEntity` is type `Kaie\Foundation\Uuid\Database\EloquentBuilder` while the query based to the where closure is of type `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`.